# Logging Laravel user in to progress web app using API call

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, progressive-web-apps, laravel-passport

I've setup Passport routes to login users via an API for a mobile app. However, part of the mobile app use a webview to display gated content and part of it pull from the API for other content.

Once a user logs into the app using the API, I need them to also be logged into the web content at the same time.

However, there is no session created with the API. How can I both login and logout users thru the API in a way that will carryover when displaying a webview?

I've tried using this on my `API\LoginController.php` to perform the login:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasSession()) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
    } else {
        // Login user for PWA pages.
        \Session::start();
        \Auth::login($this->guard()->user());
    }
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user());
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user): ?JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json(['token' => $user->createToken(config('app.name'))->accessToken], 200);
}
```

This extends the base Laravel default `LoginController.php` but overrides these methods to support JSON responses.

The associated route:

```
Route::post('login')->name('api.auth.login')->uses('API\\Auth\\LoginController@login');
```

Login works fine when called thru the API but does not persist the session into the webview.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this using Hypnopompia's solution in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/135

Extracted his code and simply inserted it into a `web` middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;
use DB;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;
use Lcobucci\JWT\ValidationData;

class ApiTokenWebLogin
{
    /**
     * @param string $tokenId
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function isAccessTokenRevoked($tokenId)
    {
        return DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
            ->where('id', $tokenId)
            ->where('revoked', 1)
            ->exists();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $jwt
     *
     * @return array|bool
     */
    private function validateToken($jwt)
    {
        try {
            $token = (new Parser())->parse($jwt);

            if ($token->verify(new Sha256(), file_get_contents(Passport::keyPath('oauth-public.key'))) === false) {
                return false;
            }

            // Ensure access token hasn't expired.
            $data = new ValidationData();
            $data->setCurrentTime(time());

            if ($token->validate($data) === false) {
                return false;
            }

            // Check if token has been revoked.
            if ($this->isAccessTokenRevoked($token->getClaim('jti'))) {
                return false;
            }

            return [
                'user_id' => $token->getClaim('sub'),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false; // Decoder error.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        // If user passed a valid Passport token, then login to the webview.
        if (!empty($token) && $request->hasSession() && !Auth::check() && $user_id = $this->validateToken($token)) {
            \Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```